# How do I add a custom incrementing counter for results with the same value?

Tags: sql-server, counter, increment

I have the following MySQL query for renaming files from a specific location :

```
SELECT REPLACE('copy "S:' + RIGHT(Path, LEN(Path) - 10) + '.eps" ','/','\'),' "C:\EPS\' + barcode + ' ().eps"'
FROM product 
WHERE barcode IN ('1234','6789);
```

Which give me the following results, which is fine:

```
copy "S:\C\image1.eps"  |  "C:\EPS\1234 ().eps"
copy "S:\C\image2.eps"  |  "C:\EPS\1234 ().eps"
copy "S:\C\image3.eps"  |  "C:\EPS\1234 ().eps"
copy "S:\C\image4.eps"  |  "C:\EPS\1234 ().eps"
copy "S:\C\image5.eps"  |  "C:\EPS\6789 ().eps"
copy "S:\C\image6.eps"  |  "C:\EPS\6789 ().eps"
```

How will I add a custom counter per matching value to get the following results?

```
copy "S:\C\image1.eps"  |  "C:\EPS\1234 (1).eps"
copy "S:\C\image2.eps"  |  "C:\EPS\1234 (2).eps"
copy "S:\C\image3.eps"  |  "C:\EPS\1234 (3).eps"
copy "S:\C\image4.eps"  |  "C:\EPS\1234 (4).eps"
copy "S:\C\image5.eps"  |  "C:\EPS\6789 (1).eps"
copy "S:\C\image6.eps"  |  "C:\EPS\6789 (2).eps"
```

Comment: Are you sure that you tagged the correct database? This code does not look like MySql.

Comment: MySQL can't add together strings, so this isn't MySQL or if is, it's busted.

Comment: I assure the query is running perfectly and is MySql. I just need know find out how to add a counter so that each value can have a unique value and it has to be in numeric order.

Comment: There is absolutely no way this is MySQL. You need `CONCAT(...)` with MySQL, as `'x' + '.eps'` in MySQL is `0` since that's doing math on it. This is likely Microsoft SQL Server, which is a completely different dialect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have looks like SQL Server, so use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT REPLACE('copy "S:' + RIGHT(Path, LEN(Path) - 10) + '.eps" ','/','\'),
       '"C:\EPS\' + barcode + ' (' + 
       CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY barcode ORDER BY Path) AS VARCHAR(10))
       +').eps"'
FROM product 
WHERE barcode IN ('1234','6789');
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=afbee35bbfa51bfbe0ba55f83d53d76b).
Results:

```
copy "S:\C\image1.eps"  |  "C:\EPS\1234 (1).eps"
copy "S:\C\image2.eps"  |  "C:\EPS\1234 (2).eps"
copy "S:\C\image3.eps"  |  "C:\EPS\1234 (3).eps"
copy "S:\C\image4.eps"  |  "C:\EPS\1234 (4).eps"
copy "S:\C\image5.eps"  |  "C:\EPS\6789 (1).eps"
copy "S:\C\image6.eps"  |  "C:\EPS\6789 (2).eps"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly. Apologies for the confusion with MySQL and SQL Server.

Comment: @blinkknot you could clear up the confusion by editing the tags on your question.